# ga:sessions via API not matching interface when custom segment applied

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a custom segment that has been is use for in excess of a year which very recently started returning some very odd results in the interface. Session numbers seemed to reduce down to match the transactions numbers, so ecommerce conversion rate was ~100%.

The interface seemed to "recover" last week, but the API still will not return session numbers that are expected. Other custom segments return normal session numbers. I have queried the API with two different spreadsheet add-on and the query explorer but they all return the same - even for very short time periods where sampling is not an issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and an example of the numbers that you are seeing http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't really know how to include code or numbers in this question because I would need to provide access to my Google Analytics account - which I cannot do. The question is really whether there is any reason that only ga:sessions numbers would be affected via the API